# Output custom code on a defined sub category archive pages only in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

Actually In WooCommerce, I am trying to display some custom code (a video), only in a defined product sub-category archive page.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php if( has_term('viola-chan','product_cat' $tag_ID=18) ) { ?>
 my video html code
<?php } ?>
```

But it doesn't work and it is showing up on other parent pages too.

[Here is a live link](http://test.brideandco.co.za/product-category/wedding-dresses/viola-chan/)

How can I output custom code on a defined sub category archive pages only in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is related to display something on product category archives pages, you should use instead:

```
<?php if( is_product_category( 'viola-chan' ) ) { ?>
    <div>my video html code here</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But "viola-chan" should be your sub-category here…

---

Related documentation: [WooCommerce Conditional Tags: Product category page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5)

Answer (score 0):

Try third variable post id as shown below:

```
global $post;
if(has_term( 'viola-chan','product_cat', $post->ID )) {
    //do something if post has viola-chan term
}else{
    //do something else if the post don't have viola-chan term
}
```

Ref.- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166576/if-product-is-in-sub-category-show-code

Comment: I tried that and found that the post ID was " tag_ID=18" but when i tried to use it it wouldn't work here is that code.  `<?php if( has_term('viola-chan','product_cat', $tag_ID=18 ) ) { ?>`